# Simple aggregation using linux scripting

Tags: linux, bash, awk

Let's say I have a text file with lines like these:

```
foo 10
bar 15
bar 5
foo 30
...
```

What's the simplest way to generate the following output:

```
foo 40
bar 20
```

?

Comment: It depends on the definition of "simplest", but `printf 'foo 40\nbar 20\n'` does not seem unreasonable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will do:

```
awk '{arr[$1]+=$2;} END { for (i in arr) print i, arr[i]}'  file
```

For more information, read on Awk's associative arrays.

Answer (score 5):

Use this awk script:

```
awk '{sums[$1] += $2} END {for (a in sums) print a, sums[a]}' infile
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
foo 40
bar 20
```

[Use this awk tutorial on using associative arrays](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/03/awk-arrays-explained-with-5-practical-examples/):

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in perl:

```
perl -F -lane '$X{$F[0]}=$X{$F[0]}+$F[1];if(eof){foreach (keys %X){print $_." ".$X{$_}}}' your_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way with sort, GNU sed and bc:

```
sort infile | 
  sed -r ':a; N; s/([^ ]+) +([^\n]+)\n\1/\1 \2 +/; ta; P; D' |
  sed -r 'h; s/[^ ]+/echo/; s/$/ | bc/e; G; s/([^\n]+)\n([^ ]+).*/\2 \1/'
```

Output:

```
bar 20
foo 40
```

The first sed joins adjacent lines with the same key adding a `+` between the numbers, the second passes the sums to bc.